# combine 2 tables without header (with common column)

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 tables, say:

```
table1 = 101 1 2 3
         201 4 5 6
         301 7 8 9

table2 = 10 11 101 12
         13 14 201 15
         16 17 301 18
```

It is clear that `table1 column1` and `table2 column 3` are the columns in common. I want to join these 2 tables using `pd.join` but the problem is that my tables do not have a `header`. So how can I do this using `pandas`?

### EDIT

I am using  `pd.read_csv` to read the tables. And my tables are text files.

```
outputtable = 101 1 2 3 10 11 12
              201 4 5 6 13 14 15
              301 7 8 9 16 17 18
```

and I would like to export the `outputtable` as a text file.

Comment: What do you mean by tables here? Are these already pandas dfs? if so they **do** have a header. Are these text files? Your question is unclear, please clarify all the above

Comment: @EdChum, I edited the question. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: You've not stated what the desired df should look like, even if you did join on first and third column respectively, what do you expect to do with the remaining columns? Please show desired df

Comment: I want to join the 2 tables and export them as a txt file. So basically I want to add all the columns together in 1 table. This is the first time I use pandas. Excuse me if I am not being clear enough. I am not interested in a header for the output table.

Comment: Please show what the desired df should look like, nuances in English can mean different things to different people, for instance **add** could mean mathematical operation or to concatenate

Comment: @EdChum, ok now I get your point. I edited my question. Please see the above. Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 1):

I'd set the index to the ordinal columns that you want to merge on, then merge, rename the index name as you need to reset the index afterwards:

```
In [121]:
import io
import pandas as pd
# read in data, you can ignore the io.StringIO bit and replace with your paths
t="""101 1 2 3
         201 4 5 6
         301 7 8 9"""
table1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep='\s+', header=None)

t1="""10 11 101 12
         13 14 201 15
         16 17 301 18"""
table2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t1), sep='\s+', header=None)
​# merge the tables after setting index
merged = table1.set_index(0).merge(table2.set_index(2), left_index=True, right_index=True)
# rename the index name so it doesn't bork complaining about column 0 existing already
merged.index.name = 'index'
merged = merged.reset_index()
merged

Out[121]:
   index  1_x  2  3_x   0  1_y  3_y
0    101    1  2    3  10   11   12
1    201    4  5    6  13   14   15
2    301    7  8    9  16   17   18
```

You can now export the df as desired and pass `header=False`:

```
In [124]:
merged.to_csv(header=False, index=False)

Out[124]:
'101,1,2,3,10,11,12\n201,4,5,6,13,14,15\n301,7,8,9,16,17,18\n'
```

Comment: First, can you explain what is `sep = '\s+`? Second, I got an error: `raise KeyError('no item named %s' % str(item))
KeyError: 'no item named 0'`

Comment: `sep = '\s+'` says your CSV input is delimited by one or more whitespace characters instead of commas like in a normal CSV (CSV = Comma-Separated-Values). The string `'\s+'` is a regular expression denoting one or more of the character set `\s` which contains whitespace characters. The regular expression is passed into your CSV reading function to tell it how to separate out the items in the file.

Comment: @po6 update your question with your code that reads the csvs in, also the output from `table1.info()`, `table1.columns.tolist()` and the same for the other df

Answer (score 0):

What you can easily do as well (I assume `df1` and `df2` are your two tables):

```
l1 = [''.join(df1.applymap(str)[c].tolist()) for c in df1]
l2 = [''.join(df2.applymap(str)[c].tolist()) for c in df2]

indexes = [l1.index(i) for i in list(set(l1)-set(l2))]

In [194]: pd.concat([df2, df1.ix[:,indexes]], axis=1)
Out[194]:
    0   1    2   3  1  2  3
0  10  11  101  12  1  2  3
1  13  14  201  15  4  5  6
2  16  17  301  18  7  8  9
```